# Creating an interface in TypeScript which has a function and an arbitrary number of properties

Tags: typescript

I have the following interface

```js
interface ErrorHandler {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

And I use it like this

```js
let errorHandler: ErrorHandler = {
  name: "Your name cannot be empty",
  email: "Enter a valid email address",
  birthday: "You are too young"
};

function postData(data: any, errorHandler: ErrorHandler){
  // ...
}

postData(someData, errorHandler);
```

That's good for now. But, say you want the `errorHandler` object have a function named `handler`. How would you declare the interface?

For example, you want your `errorHandler` be like this:

```js
let errorHandler: ErrorHandler = {
  name: "Your name cannot be empty",
  email: "Enter a valid email address",
  birthday: "You are too young",
  handler: (message: string) => alert(message) 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript doesn't do very well with such types unfortunately because of the incompatibility between the index signature (which states every member of the object will be of type string) and the field `handler` which has a different type.

You can create such a type using an intersection type, but initializing it will not be posible directlym you will need to use `Object.assign` (not ideal but workable)

```
type ErrorHandler = { handler: (msg: string) => void } & { [key: string]: string; }
// Can't directly create the object, we need Object.assign
let errorHandler: ErrorHandler = Object.assign({
    name: "Your name cannot be empty",
    email: "Enter a valid email address",
    birthday: "You are too young"
}, {
    handler: (message: string) => alert(message)
});
```

The other approach would be to make the index compatible with `handler` but that would mean you can add any number of functions to the object:

```
type ErrorHandler = { handler: (msg: string) => void,  [key: string]: string | ((msg: string) => void); } 
let errorHandler: ErrorHandler = { // direct initialization 
    name: "Your name cannot be empty",
    email: "Enter a valid email address",
    birthday: "You are too young",
    handler: (message: string) => alert(message),
    // but now we can add as many functions as we want
    // which is even worse 
    badHandler: (message: string) => alert(message) 
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both solutions work in someway :) Not the way I was hoping, but hey.